# Symbolic link in ~/texmf mystery

Tags: paths, themes, kpathsea

I have TeX Live 2013 installed on Ubuntu 14.04 with kpathsea and I have a rather curious situation. I created a new beamer theme that I work on at `~/code/git/beamer/mytheme` and then I created a symbolic link to this: `~/texmf/tex/latex/beamer/themes/mytheme -> ~/code/git/beamer/mytheme/` so I could keep it in my TeX path simultaneously. When I run `kpsewhich beamerthememytheme.sty` I get nothing...however if I add an empty folder to `[...]/beamer/themes/` then `kpsewhich beamerthememytheme.sty` starts working. Anyone know why or how, if I wanted, I could have the symlinked folder in my TeX path without this dummy empty folder?

Comment: I had the same issue under Texlive 2013, the `/beamer/…/` part of the tree was not recognized. My workaround was to pack everything directly in `/temxmf/tex/latex` and it worked. This is not exactly the answer you expect, but works.

Comment: Was this for everything you put in the /beamer/.../ tree or just for symbolic links in there?

Comment: I didn't try with symbolic links, just plain files, none of them was recognized